# PageRank or SiteRank

Tags: pagerank, backlinks

When I visit our website via the root domain we have a Google PR of 3, yet when I go into any other page there is not a Google PR displayed. For example, the blog on our website does not have any Google PR.

So, this leads me to a elementary question;

Because the "Site" has a Google PR of 3, yet the blog "Pages" do not have any PR, will the link quality to other websites from the blog "Page" benefit from the "Sites" Google PR of 3. Or, does the blog "Page" that has the backlink displayed determine the valuable Google PR to gain a quality benefit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In the early days of Google the term PageRank referred to the entire site. Links and link values were calculated on a page-by-page basis creating a score for each page, however, PageRank referred to the total score of all pages and was applied to the site.

Today, PageRank is no longer publicly given so any PR score you see on the web is from almost 2 years ago. This was done to help defeat monetizers from gaming search. PageRank, as it was in the beginning, is still calculated as a SiteRank which contains sub-sets of metrics such as TrustRank.

Each page has rank calculated. When a link is created from one page to another page, it is the *pages* rank that is shared. So a totally worthless page on a site that ordinarily ranks well will not pass much value. In the early days, however, it was the sites rank that was shared. That ended a long time ago as an effort to better calculate the value of links.

Comment: Yep. TL;DR PR is per page, not per site

Comment: @JohnConde The whole PR confusion drives me nuts! I understand it- still it drives me nuts!! Google [*******] the pooch in the early days with the whole PR thing. They should have just kept their mouths shut. It would have been a lot easier on everybody that way. ;-)

Comment: Agreed! But it was PR that made them famous. A catch 22 of sorts.

Comment: @JohnConde It jus wooda bin nice if they had a bit more fore-thought on at least this one thing. I blame my lack of hair on their PR confusion... why not? Who's gunna argue??

Comment: do you have any references for your answer?

Comment: @Mousey I have read the original research paper and about half of all of the patents plus one highly detailed schema/business rules internal document written for G management. I have also read some of the engineers work external to G. As well, I am familiar with the technologies that G tells us they use. What are you specifically asking about? I am thinking of cleaning up the last paragraph on this one later. How can I make this clearer for you and others??

Comment: I'd like a link to the part about pagerank being about the individual page and ignoring the rank of the site/domain authority

Comment: @Mousey I should rewrite this answer to be better anyway. PR, when you did see it in toolbars and such **originally** was a public number that applied sitewide. Later, in toolbars, Google would report a number based upon the page you were viewing. If it was the home page, then PR would be representative of the sitewide number. Keep in mind that this is just a number that Google reported and did not have anything to do with reality. Google killed this feature a couple of years ago now and yet PR is still all the chatter. There is no one link, this has been described over a decade.

Comment: @Mousey Keep in mind that PR was never a direct link to actual metrics. It was a representational number. The original research paper describes PR as being calculated on a page by page basis, however, a cumulative/average (kind of) score would represent the sites PR. Things like trust scores and other metrics besides PR push PR down the list as a sitewide metric. Still the home page would somewhat represents a cumulative score since it is the top of the link hierarchy. The problem is, PR is no longer a public metric you can grab a-hold of and was only calculated quarterly or less anyway.

Comment: moz.com calculate a PR based on what factors they take into accoutn

Comment: Moz has their own metrics, however, any PR you see on any site including MOZ is 2-3 years old and frozen in time. They use the API to get this stat but it is bogus. Most people do not know this. This is the first link I found, however, there are more that are definitive. No more updates to PR. http://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-no-more-pagerank-updates-this-year-173676 We seem to answer this question a few times a year here. You have to understand that there is money in SEO even if it just a website so misinformation is rampant and parroting BS the norm. Not here though.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper meta tags and also register your site in google webmaster tools and bing search engine. A meta tag is generated when you register your site in google and bing just copy the same and paste below the head tag.. never worry about page rank.or anu thing else.